# Как уменьшить avg loss в обучении сверточной нейросети?

Tags: нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение

Обучаю нейронную сеть (проект [darknet](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet)) на датасете [cityscapes](https://www.cityscapes-dataset.com/). Использую квантизованную сеть **yolov3-tiny** с **xnor**. Именно ее, ибо надо для исследовательской работы.
Первые 2500 итераций функция потери уменьшалась. Но затем на протяжении 2500 итераций **current average loss** скачет от 85 до 98 и не уменьшается.
Мне известно, что для **yolov3-tiny** требуется бОльшее количество итераций, но такое поведение функции заставляет меня думать, что что-то идёт не так. 
Вот листинг моего .cfg файла.

```
[net]
# Testing
#batch=1
#subdivisions=1
# Training
batch=64
subdivisions=64
width=416
height=416
channels=3
momentum=0.9
decay=0.0005
angle=0
saturation = 1.5
exposure = 1.5
hue=.1

learning_rate=0.001
burn_in=1000
max_batches = 54000
policy=steps
steps=43200,48600
scales=.1,.1

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=16
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[maxpool]
size=2
stride=2

[convolutional]
xnor=1
bin_output=1
batch_normalize=1
filters=32
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[maxpool]
size=2
stride=2

[convolutional]
xnor=1
bin_output=1
batch_normalize=1
filters=64
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[maxpool]
size=2
stride=2

[convolutional]
xnor=1
bin_output=1
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[maxpool]
size=2
stride=2

[convolutional]
xnor=1
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[maxpool]
size=2
stride=2

[convolutional]
xnor=1
bin_output=1
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[maxpool]
size=2
stride=1

[convolutional]
xnor=1
bin_output=1
batch_normalize=1
filters=1024
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

###########

[convolutional]
xnor=1
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
filters=96
activation=linear



[yolo]
mask = 3,4,5
anchors = 10,14,  23,27,  37,58,  81,82,  135,169,  344,319
classes=27
num=6
jitter=.3
ignore_thresh = .7
truth_thresh = 1
random=1

[route]
layers = -4

[convolutional]
xnor=1
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[upsample]
stride=2

[route]
layers = -1, 8

[convolutional]
xnor=1
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky


[convolutional]
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
filters=96
activation=linear

[yolo]
mask = 0,1,2
anchors = 10,14,  23,27,  37,58,  81,82,  135,169,  344,319
classes=27
num=6
jitter=.3
ignore_thresh = .7
truth_thresh = 1
random=1
```

А это небольшой кусок лога с консоли во время обучения. Собственно, последняя строчка и говорит о том, что на 4626 итерации потеря ~87, средняя ~89.

```
Region 23 Avg IOU: 0.265518, Class: 0.435117, Obj: 0.148009, No Obj: 0.005844, .5R: 0.196078, .75R: 0.019608, count: 51 
Region 16 Avg IOU: 0.580091, Class: 0.670664, Obj: 0.032476, No Obj: 0.005750, .5R: 0.625000, .75R: 0.375000, count: 8 
Region 23 Avg IOU: 0.248095, Class: 0.356050, Obj: 0.196296, No Obj: 0.009592, .5R: 0.228070, .75R: 0.035088, count: 57 
Region 16 Avg IOU: 0.722499, Class: 0.717814, Obj: 0.203179, No Obj: 0.010187, .5R: 0.833333, .75R: 0.583333, count: 12 
Region 23 Avg IOU: 0.200099, Class: 0.449851, Obj: 0.263441, No Obj: 0.007661, .5R: 0.125000, .75R: 0.020833, count: 48 
Region 16 Avg IOU: 0.627702, Class: 0.639825, Obj: 0.076752, No Obj: 0.008924, .5R: 0.894737, .75R: 0.105263, count: 19 
Region 23 Avg IOU: 0.335099, Class: 0.582281, Obj: 0.213293, No Obj: 0.006483, .5R: 0.285714, .75R: 0.000000, count: 21 
Region 16 Avg IOU: 0.591135, Class: 0.515837, Obj: 0.084826, No Obj: 0.007397, .5R: 0.777778, .75R: 0.222222, count: 9 
Region 23 Avg IOU: 0.270088, Class: 0.379691, Obj: 0.103391, No Obj: 0.007345, .5R: 0.222222, .75R: 0.066667, count: 45 
Region 16 Avg IOU: 0.637949, Class: 0.578599, Obj: 0.057576, No Obj: 0.007756, .5R: 0.875000, .75R: 0.250000, count: 8 
Region 23 Avg IOU: 0.256824, Class: 0.451845, Obj: 0.224611, No Obj: 0.008402, .5R: 0.217391, .75R: 0.043478, count: 46 
Region 16 Avg IOU: 0.540718, Class: 0.335908, Obj: 0.040383, No Obj: 0.008715, .5R: 0.583333, .75R: 0.166667, count: 12 
Region 23 Avg IOU: 0.235176, Class: 0.455385, Obj: 0.085092, No Obj: 0.007274, .5R: 0.129032, .75R: 0.064516, count: 31 
Region 16 Avg IOU: 0.641580, Class: 0.503497, Obj: 0.024668, No Obj: 0.006794, .5R: 0.750000, .75R: 0.250000, count: 4 
Region 23 Avg IOU: 0.503209, Class: 0.463772, Obj: 0.067609, No Obj: 0.008881, .5R: 0.534884, .75R: 0.139535, count: 43 
Region 16 Avg IOU: 0.678923, Class: 0.653871, Obj: 0.121154, No Obj: 0.008613, .5R: 1.000000, .75R: 0.357143, count: 14 
Region 23 Avg IOU: 0.421022, Class: 0.605306, Obj: 0.173600, No Obj: 0.007411, .5R: 0.470588, .75R: 0.000000, count: 17 
Region 16 Avg IOU: 0.639299, Class: 0.530710, Obj: 0.042849, No Obj: 0.008491, .5R: 1.000000, .75R: 0.125000, count: 8 
Region 23 Avg IOU: 0.208921, Class: 0.411707, Obj: 0.194609, No Obj: 0.007580, .5R: 0.126984, .75R: 0.000000, count: 63 
Region 16 Avg IOU: 0.632487, Class: 0.659411, Obj: 0.092881, No Obj: 0.008519, .5R: 0.812500, .75R: 0.312500, count: 16 
Region 23 Avg IOU: 0.312103, Class: 0.431079, Obj: 0.095346, No Obj: 0.005578, .5R: 0.166667, .75R: 0.000000, count: 30 
Region 16 Avg IOU: 0.684433, Class: 0.827545, Obj: 0.198062, No Obj: 0.009626, .5R: 0.916667, .75R: 0.333333, count: 12 
Region 23 Avg IOU: 0.448249, Class: 0.579867, Obj: 0.193012, No Obj: 0.006854, .5R: 0.545455, .75R: 0.045455, count: 22 
Region 16 Avg IOU: 0.658382, Class: 0.645144, Obj: 0.113465, No Obj: 0.009089, .5R: 0.900000, .75R: 0.300000, count: 10 
Region 23 Avg IOU: 0.257555, Class: 0.272910, Obj: 0.125294, No Obj: 0.007114, .5R: 0.225806, .75R: 0.032258, count: 31 
Region 16 Avg IOU: 0.643501, Class: 0.852559, Obj: 0.154642, No Obj: 0.011873, .5R: 0.750000, .75R: 0.333333, count: 12 
Region 23 Avg IOU: 0.418301, Class: 0.784098, Obj: 0.319215, No Obj: 0.007885, .5R: 0.523810, .75R: 0.095238, count: 21 
Region 16 Avg IOU: 0.706821, Class: 0.737151, Obj: 0.021006, No Obj: 0.009046, .5R: 1.000000, .75R: 0.500000, count: 4 
Region 23 Avg IOU: 0.239129, Class: 0.391339, Obj: 0.172061, No Obj: 0.008939, .5R: 0.172840, .75R: 0.012346, count: 81 
Region 16 Avg IOU: 0.646025, Class: 0.577434, Obj: 0.140843, No Obj: 0.010109, .5R: 0.818182, .75R: 0.090909, count: 11 
Region 23 Avg IOU: 0.301333, Class: 0.430824, Obj: 0.230992, No Obj: 0.007980, .5R: 0.148148, .75R: 0.000000, count: 27 
Region 16 Avg IOU: 0.629436, Class: 0.614282, Obj: 0.078061, No Obj: 0.008712, .5R: 0.846154, .75R: 0.153846, count: 13 
Region 23 Avg IOU: 0.232578, Class: 0.454189, Obj: 0.197745, No Obj: 0.008565, .5R: 0.170213, .75R: 0.021277, count: 47 
Region 16 Avg IOU: 0.692399, Class: 0.726789, Obj: 0.127101, No Obj: 0.010190, .5R: 0.769231, .75R:

0.307692, count: 13 
Region 23 Avg IOU: 0.345320, Class: 0.530280, Obj: 0.103126, No Obj: 0.007430, .5R: 0.212121, .75R: 0.030303, count: 33 
Region 16 Avg IOU: 0.594100, Class: 0.562634, Obj: 0.026976, No Obj: 0.006820, .5R: 0.666667, .75R: 0.166667, count: 6 
Region 23 Avg IOU: 0.289213, Class: 0.276136, Obj: 0.055291, No Obj: 0.007096, .5R: 0.157895, .75R: 0.052632, count: 19 
Region 16 Avg IOU: 0.614991, Class: 0.574934, Obj: 0.105981, No Obj: 0.008818, .5R: 0.733333, .75R: 0.266667, count: 15 
Region 23 Avg IOU: 0.356659, Class: 0.475276, Obj: 0.139249, No Obj: 0.008407, .5R: 0.357143, .75R: 0.035714, count: 28 
Region 16 Avg IOU: 0.725138, Class: 0.771429, Obj: 0.123076, No Obj: 0.009726, .5R: 1.000000, .75R: 0.125000, count: 8 
Region 23 Avg IOU: 0.319792, Class: 0.448898, Obj: 0.110685, No Obj: 0.008141, .5R: 0.325000, .75R: 0.000000, count: 40 
Region 16 Avg IOU: 0.659288, Class: 0.399692, Obj: 0.038270, No Obj: 0.009124, .5R: 0.888889, .75R: 0.333333, count: 9 
Region 23 Avg IOU: 0.233994, Class: 0.404323, Obj: 0.105947, No Obj: 0.006786, .5R: 0.078947, .75R: 0.000000, count: 38 
Region 16 Avg IOU: 0.597520, Class: 0.728333, Obj: 0.115807, No Obj: 0.007809, .5R: 0.692308, .75R: 0.153846, count: 13 
Region 23 Avg IOU: 0.238322, Class: 0.445596, Obj: 0.124153, No Obj: 0.007673, .5R: 0.127273, .75R: 0.000000, count: 55 
Region 16 Avg IOU: 0.659071, Class: 0.672420, Obj: 0.086053, No Obj: 0.010427, .5R: 0.900000, .75R: 0.400000, count: 10 
Region 23 Avg IOU: 0.304247, Class: 0.408292, Obj: 0.118676, No Obj: 0.005135, .5R: 0.218750, .75R: 0.062500, count: 32 
Region 16 Avg IOU: 0.611357, Class: 0.789537, Obj: 0.105030, No Obj: 0.010327, .5R: 0.714286, .75R: 0.000000, count: 14 
Region 23 Avg IOU: 0.263716, Class: 0.535194, Obj: 0.167545, No Obj: 0.008088, .5R: 0.222222, .75R: 0.027778, count: 36 
Region 16 Avg IOU: 0.631452, Class: 0.647641, Obj: 0.060545, No Obj: 0.007234, .5R: 0.857143, .75R: 0.142857, count: 7 
Region 23 Avg IOU: 0.402038, Class: 0.450376, Obj: 0.040484, No Obj: 0.002890, .5R: 0.312500, .75R: 0.000000, count: 16 
Region 16 Avg IOU: 0.709563, Class: 0.813733, Obj: 0.090699, No Obj: 0.007109, .5R: 0.888889, .75R: 0.222222, count: 9 
Region 23 Avg IOU: 0.212719, Class: 0.303074, Obj: 0.239371, No Obj: 0.009795, .5R: 0.058824, .75R: 0.000000, count: 68 
Region 16 Avg IOU: 0.663039, Class: 0.514077, Obj: 0.126791, No Obj: 0.008837, .5R: 0.785714, .75R: 0.357143, count: 14 
Region 23 Avg IOU: 0.298329, Class: 0.333948, Obj: 0.061829, No Obj: 0.006843, .5R: 0.200000, .75R: 0.000000, count: 55 
Region 16 Avg IOU: 0.629905, Class: 0.500352, Obj: 0.029201, No Obj: 0.007471, .5R: 0.700000, .75R: 0.200000, count: 10 
Region 23 Avg IOU: 0.350497, Class: 0.479209, Obj: 0.077526, No Obj: 0.005723, .5R: 0.242424, .75R: 0.030303, count: 33 
Region 16 Avg IOU: 0.593396, Class: 0.579723, Obj: 0.029702, No Obj: 0.008266, .5R: 0.800000, .75R: 0.200000, count: 10 
Region 23 Avg IOU: 0.217339, Class: 0.509800, Obj: 0.139089, No Obj: 0.008110, .5R: 0.190476, .75R: 0.000000, count: 21 
Region 16 Avg IOU: 0.582936, Class: 0.681505, Obj: 0.077898, No Obj: 0.008054, .5R: 1.000000, .75R: 0.000000, count: 9 
Region 23 Avg IOU: 0.299198, Class: 0.306460, Obj: 0.146345, No Obj: 0.007363, .5R: 0.218182, .75R: 0.054545, count: 55 

4626: 87.837746, 89.782654 avg loss, 0.001000 rate, 28.972000 seconds, 296064 images
```